# Foursquare API latitude longitude doesn't return results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foursquare

I'm making this http call for foursquare api and I don't get any results back if I use 'll' parameter. As soon as I remove it and enter 'near: 10011', I get results. What am I doing wrong? I need to use latitude longitude.

```
var data = $http({
      url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore',
      method: 'jsonp',
      params: {query: selectedQuery, limit:7, ll: '44.3,37.2', client_id: clientId, client_secret: clientSecret, price: selectedPrice.priceValue, v: 20140806, callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the quotes around the coordinates like  `ll: 44.3,37.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You should resolve the returned promise:

```
var data = function () {
 return $http({
   url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore',
   method: 'jsonp',
   params: {query: selectedQuery, limit:7, ll: '44.3,37.2', client_id: clientId, client_secret: clientSecret, price: selectedPrice.priceValue, v: 20140806, callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}
 }).then(function success (response) {
     return response; 
    }, 
    function error (response) {
     return response;
    });
//Call the function 
data();
```